# compiler hint in derived template class pointer conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, inheritance

How can I define a compiler error message that will show up when trying to compile the following code?

```cpp
template<int n> struct Base{};

struct Derived: Base<2>{};

int main(){
    Derived x;
    Base<1>* p;
    p=&x; // a compiler hint like "Derived has dimension 2, not 1" would be nice.
}
```

As intended, the above code generates the compilation error `cannot convert 'Derived*' to 'Base<1>*' in assignment`, and what I wish to achieve is an augmentation of this error message with a phrase like `because Derived has dimension 2, not 1`.

Background on my application:
I have template virtual problem classes with template dimension, and a template solver class with memory depending of the dimension of the template argument, which is a problem class derived. When passing a derived problem of incompatible dimension, I want to assist the user in identifying the compile error by hinting at the dimension. I do not want to augment the solver with an additional template argument of dimension.

Comment: You should already pretty much get that error message?

Comment: My compiler gives me the error `cannot convert 'Derived*' to 'Base<1>*' in assignment`, so what you want pretty much already happens anyway

Comment: Mixing static polymorphism (templates) with dynamic polymorphism is usually a design smell. (the only thing I might expect is for Base to be some kind of abstract baseclass). So you're trying to solve something and came up with this, but WHAT is it you are trying to solve?

Comment: I've tried GCC, Clang, and MSVC, and all of them reject this code with default settings.

Comment: While I agree with your comments, imagine a less toyish example with additional layers between Base and Derived, or where Base and Derived have many template arguments, and/or when n is a template argument within a template argument of Base, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Exactly, and I had tried with ``static_assert``. I just cannot figure out in which routine. I tried operator= and copy constructur, each with template for right-hand side argument of Base, in order to check right-hand-side-Base's dimension. However, both destroys all the default routines, so I hoped for a more practical approach.

Comment: You cannot define custom error messages for built-in types (pointers are built-in types). You can define your own smart (or nor so smart) pointer  class and there you can define your own error messages using `static_assert`.

Comment: You could try to add a conversion operator in Derived to Base<N> (and use enable_if to exclude N=2). Then in the implementation you add a static assert that always fails. Not sure it will work for pointers though, easier if you have a smart pointer like n.m could be an AI suggests.